# On a parallelogram spanned by two vectors, how do you represent a point along the short diagonal?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Say you have two vectors $\vec a, \ \vec b$. You draw the first triangle $\triangle ABC$ spanned by these. Basically, that's the triangle on the left side of the short diagonal of the parallelogram spanned by them.

If you let $\vec a, \vec b$ be the vectors out from the point $A$, and you mark a point $D$ along $BC$ such that it cuts it into two lengths of ratio $1:2$, how would you represent this point in terms of $\vec a, \vec b$?

Illustration:

[image]

As I'm writing this, I think I'm spotting it though. Maybe someone can verify.

Since $\vec{BC} = \vec b - \vec a$, we get $\vec{BD} = \frac13(\vec b - \vec a)$.

Then $\vec{AD} = \vec a + \frac13 (\vec b - \vec a)$.

Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, and it will be an average of $a$, $b$, that is $\frac{2}{3}a + \frac{1}{3} b$

Comment: Yes that is correct and please see _In Vectors_ section in the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_formula